# Porting bookdown to distill::distill_article doesn't support theorem environment

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Trying to implement theorem environment to R distill::article. Followed the instructions from the books on Rmarkdown and Bookdown, and the [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-number.html)

I found that theorem environments were processed well for

```
bookdown::html_document2:
    base_format: rmarkdown::html_document
```

and

```
bookdown::html_document2:
    base_format: pagedown::html_paged
```

However, it doesn't work for `distill_article`. Anyone knows why it doesn't work?

The following is a minimal reproducible example.

````
---
title: "Port the bookdown features to Rmarkdown"
author: "Bookdown Rmarkdown"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    base_format: distill::distill_article
---

# Theorems

```{theorem, name="Pythagorean theorem"}
For a right triangle, if $c$ denotes the length of the hypotenuse
and $a$ and $b$ denote the lengths of the other two sides, we have
$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2.$$
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking the codes in distll_article.R, I think that I figured out why the theorem was not display. By default, in distll_article, `knitr_options$opts_chunk$echo` is assigned with the value `FALSE`, which I think hides the theorem environment as it was defined as a code chunk in bookdown. To switch the value, adding the following code chunk right after the yaml header will do the work.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````